# Invalid Subdomains of Addon Domains Show Content Fom Main Domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain, plesk

I have a website - `www.example.com`.

There is content at `www.example.com/content.html`.

I have an addon domain called `www.addon.com`.

If I type `invalidsubdomain.addon.com/content.html` into the address bar, I see the content hosted at `www.example.com/content.html`.

Why might this be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the best answer I've found: http://enarion.net/web/plesk/plesk-catchall-subdomains/

Apparently, the problem is with wildcard subdomains.  Plesk can be configured to handle these domains (some SSH is required).  Alternatively, the default domain for the account can be changed to something more appropriate as a "catch-all" page.